# How to find the smallest possible $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $n=2k_1+1=3k_2+2=4k_3+3$?

Tags: prime-numbers

I start solving this by trying $2k_1+1=3k_2+2$, but it doesn't make any sense, because I still have to use $4k_3+3$.

If I sum all three equations together, I get $3n=(2k_1+3k_2+4k_3)+6$. This may be, but how can I determine the factors $k_1, k_2 $and$\ k_3$?

Comment: Hint:  you can rewrite this as $n\equiv -1 \pmod {2,3,4}$.  Though, in truth, the numbers here are so small that trial and error is probably just as fast.

Comment: Sorry, high school student here. Is there another way solving this without using modular arithmetic?

Comment: Sure, trial and error.  Really, that just takes a few seconds.  But...you don't need modular arithmetic to follow my hint.  All I said is that your conditions can be rewritten to say that $n$ is, simultaneously, $1$ less than a multiple or each of $2$, $3$, and $4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to solve the syatem:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
2x+1=3y+2
\\ 3y+2=4z+3
\end{matrix}\right.$$
The sultions are:
$$x=6k+5 \vee y=4k+3 \vee z=3k+2, k\in Z$$
We have to find the value of $k$ for which $12k+11$ is prime, so $k=0$. We can conclude that the smallest $n$ is $11$.